# Adapt IntentService implementation to wait for onServiceConnected()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have a service that is always running. It can be started and bound to as well. Here is an excerpt of the service:

```
class LocalService extends Service {
  LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

  class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() { return LocalService.this; }
  }

  int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
  }
}
```

This service is started on application launch by the MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  void onCreate(Bundle) {
    // ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    ComponentName component = startService(intent);
    Assert.assertNotNull(component);
  }
}
```

I need to pass commands to my service. In order to do that, I have an abstract service `LocalBindingService` that I can inherit from that when started, binds to my service, call a method on it, then exits:

```
class LocalBindingService extends IntentService implements ServiceConnection {
  abstract void onLocalBinding(Intent intent, LocalService service);

  Intent mIntent;

  void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mIntent = intent;
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    boolean serviceFound = bindService(localIntent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Assert.assertTrue(serviceFound);
  }
  void onDestroy() {
    unbindService(this);
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder iBinder) {
    LocalService service = ((LocalService.LocalBinder) iBinder).getService();
    onLocalBinding(mIntent, service);
  }
  void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName) {
    // nothing
  }
}
```

Since it inherits from `IntentService` it runs in a separate thred. This way it should be easy to simply invoke a method on `LocalService`:

```
class NotifyService extends LocalBindingService {
  void onLocalBinding(Intent intent, LocalService service) {
    service.notify();
  }
}
```

However, my problem is that `LocalBindingService` exits before binding occurs. From what I gather, it should inherit from `Service` instead of `IntentService`, which means I have to handle the thread manually. When looking at the example from the [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService), I fail to understand how to adapt my code. I don't really understand this use of `Looper` in the example and whether I need it at all.

Could someone help me adapt this piece of code to achieve this behavior? Thanks,

Comment: "I need to pass commands to my service" -- so, call `startService()` to send a command to `LocalService`. Done. "my problem is that LocalBindingService exits before binding occurs" -- of course. The point behind `IntentService` is for the service to be destroyed once `onHandleIntent()` returns, if there are no more commands queued up for that service. `IntentService` is designed to drive synchronous APIs, not asynchronous ones.

Comment: @CommonsWare When I say commands I mean to invoke methods on `LocalService`, where some parameters may not be possible to be passed through an `Intent`. I understand `IntentService` is not designed for this behavior, hence why I want to change `LocalBindingService` implementation. My problem is to invoke methods once bound to the service, from another service.